# How to output with 3 digits after the decimal point with C++ stream?

Tags: c++, floating-point, iostream

Given a variable of float type, how to output it with 3 digits after the decimal point, using iostream in C++?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) and [`precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    double f = 3.14159;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
    cout.precision(3);
    cout << f << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `3.142`

Comment: This works for 3.14159 but it does not work for 13.14159. Your solution only works for numbers less than 10.

Comment: @manler You are right, my original post did not, but the final one (the one I edited 11 minutes ago) works correctly. I verified it with 2 and 3 digits before the decimal point, and it prints 3 digits as expected.

Answer (score 10):

This one does show "13.142"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double f = 13.14159;
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(3) << f << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No! it outputs `13.142` rather than `13.141`!

Comment: you're right @ChenLi I edited my comment

Answer (score 7):

You can get fixed number of fractional digits (and many other things) by using the `iomanip` header. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double pi = 3.141592653589;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << pi << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

will output:

```
3.14
```

Note that both `fixed` and `setprecision` change the stream permanently so, if you want to localise the effects, you can save the information beforehand and restore it afterwards:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double pi = 3.141592653589;

    std::cout << pi << '\n';

    // Save flags/precision.
    std::ios_base::fmtflags oldflags = std::cout.flags();
    std::streamsize oldprecision = std::cout.precision();

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << pi << '\n';
    std::cout << pi << '\n';

    // Restore flags/precision.
    std::cout.flags (oldflags);
    std::cout.precision (oldprecision);

    std::cout << pi << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
3.14159
3.14
3.14
3.14159
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to save and restore the stream settings, very helpful.

Comment: use this line " using namespace std; "for more clean code

Comment: @Khaled, there are arguments for and against that which are complex enough that they won't fit within a comment box :-) I myself prefer explicit namespaces for all but the simplest programs or, at a minimum, using specific items *within* a namespace rather than importing the whole lot. However, that particular discussion is tangential to the question and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print numbers with precision of 3 digits after decimal, just add the following thing before printing the number `cout << std::setprecision(3) << desired_number`. Don't forget to add `#include <iomanip>` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In general, *precision* is the maximum number of digits displayed. The manipulator *fixed* will set up the output stream for displaying values in *fixed* format. In *fixed* the *precision* is the number of digits after the decimal point. The *setprecision* allows setting the precision used for displaying floating-point values, it takes an integer argument.

```
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(3) << f << endl;
```

You may unset *fixed* using *cout.unsetf(ios::fixed)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). For example ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/v7hnPqovj)):

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <numbers>

int main() {
  std::cout << std::format("{:.3f}", std::numbers::pi_v<double>);
}
```

Output:

```
3.142
```

This method has a number of advantages compared to using I/O manipulators:

- It doesn't change the stream state and therefore doesn't interfere with later operations.
- The default is locale-independent.
- It is likely faster despite constructing `std::string`.
- It is less verbose.

In C++23 you can use `std::print` and avoid constructing `std::string`.